# Html Agility Pack parsing table into object

Tags: c#, foreach, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

So I have HTML like this:

```
<tr class="row1">
        <td class="id">123</td>
        <td class="date">2014-08-08</td>
        <td class="time">12:31:25</td>
        <td class="notes">something here</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row0">
        <td class="id">432</td>
        <td class="date">2015-02-09</td>
        <td class="time">12:22:21</td>
        <td class="notes">something here</td>
</tr>
```

And it continues like that for each customer row. I want to parse contents of each table row to an object. I've tried few methods but I can't seem to get it work right.

This is what I have currently

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (HtmlNode row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='customerlist']//tr"))
{
    Customer cust = new Customer();
    foreach (HtmlNode info in row.SelectNodes("//td"))
    {
        if (info.GetAttributeValue("class", String.Empty) == "id")
        {
            cust.ID = info.InnerText;
        }
        if (info.GetAttributeValue("class", String.Empty) == "date")
        {
            cust.DateAdded = info.InnerText;
        }
        if (info.GetAttributeValue("class", String.Empty) == "time")
        {
            cust.TimeAdded = info.InnerText;
        }
        if (info.GetAttributeValue("class", String.Empty) == "notes")
        {
            cust.Notes = info.InnerText;
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(cust.ID + " " + cust.TimeAdded + " " + cust.DateAdded + " " + cust.Notes);
}
```

It works to the point that it prints info of the **last row of the table** on each loop. I'm just missing something very simple but cannot see what.

Also is my way of creating the object fine, or should I use a constructor and create the object from variables? E.g.

```
    string Notes = String.Empty;
if (info.GetAttributeValue("class", String.Empty) == "notes")
{
    Notes = info.InnerText;
}
..
Customer cust = new Customer(id, other_variables, Notes, etc);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your XPath query is wrong. You need to use `td` instead of `//td`:

```
foreach (HtmlNode info in row.SelectNodes("td"))
```

Passing `//td` to `SelectNodes()` will match *all* `<td>` elements in the document, hence your inner loop runs 8 times instead of 4 times, and the last 4 times always overrides the values previously set in your `Customer` object.

See [XPath Examples](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx)